# GearVRのデベロッパーモード動作時の判定

Tags: untagged

Oculus Mobile SDKを使ってGearVRで動作するアプリを開発しているのですが、

- デベロッパーモードを使って**GearVRに取り付けずに動作している**状態と、
- デベロッパーモードでない状態で**GearVRに取り付けて動作している状態**

をプログラムから判定することはできるのでしょうか？